# AggCat Categorization returns common => nil

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, categorization, customer-account-data-api

After following the instructions on the IPP customer account data site regarding [categorization](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/0005_service_features/0050_categorization) and setting up an app to intake transactions from a users bank account I am receiving common => nil for each transaction. Is this a production only feature or should the test app receive categorizations on transactions?

Comment: Please include whatever code you are using which doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Intuit has setup a dummy FI( called CC_Bank, institutionId - 100000) for testing CAD APIs. I guess, you are testing these calls against CC_Bank.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

In getAccountTransaction call, CC_Bank returns a static list of transactions(with categorization).

You can refer the following steps to get new tokens and test API calls using ApiExplorer.

ApiExplorer Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

Key generation using openssl - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

After generating these keys, you can create a sample app with the public key. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0015_create_an_cad_integration

then use the .p12 file with pwd for SAML assertion in apiexplorer Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

You can refer/use java/.net sample apps to understand the app flow.

Ref Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits

*Update*

It is not a prod only feature. For real FIs, you should get categorized data.

Thanks

Comment: I have been testing out with my own credentials, but am receiving no categorization on transactions from the past six months. I have enabled categorization on my application.